# how to match devise old password?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, passwords

I am trying to follow the tips here - [Rails 3 / Devise: Password salt no longer being created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606728/rails-3-devise-password-salt-no-longer-being-created)

But none of it works - both `valid_password?` and `password_digest`. `password_digest` gets a protected method and `valid_password?` returns empty.

When my user changes their password, I let them enter an old password and if this matches the encrypted password in the database, then I will update the user's password.

Comment: Which Devise version are you using? Which encryptor are you using ?

Comment: i'm using 1.4.2 - i'm not sure what encryptor it uses, would you tell me how to find that out and how to use it so i can encrypt the user entered old password?

Answer (score 0):

to let the user enter the original password, just add a :current_password to the params and then use @user.update_with_password(params[:user]) to update with validation of current password.

```
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :current_password %> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i><br />
<%= f.password_field :current_password %>
</div>
```